# Postgresql: direct replication on demand

Tags: database, postgresql, clone, database-replication

I have two Postgresql databases (on different servers): lets call them stable and unstable. The stable is for read purposes only. From time to time the the stable is updated to the current unstable.

I would like to improve the update process. Dumping to a file and restoring is not possible any more due to the size of database. I found [many replication tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication%2C_Clustering%2C_and_Connection_Pooling) designed for a master-slave configuration, but that is not exactly what I do, as the slave (stable) is updated on demand. The tools seem to be more complicated that the problem I want them to solve.

Ideally, I would like a simple tool with interface like `pg_replicate source target` which would result in `target` db being exact clone of `source` and the data being transfered directly between the two database servers (they are connected by a local network) without creating large temporary files. The database size is 50 GB and growing, so transfering SQL inserts might not suffice.

So, is there a tool which could do it? Or anything close?

Comment: pg_dump/pg_restore over a pipe comes to mind. You could also use [pg_basebackup](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgbasebackup.html) to take a backup and use that as a (disconnected) clone

Comment: I'd use WAL shipping with no limit on the standby lag and a `recovery.conf` that sets a recovery time. If you force a `CHECKPOINT` on the unstable it should be possible to target that time for restore. Main downside here is that if the churn rate of updates on the unstable site is very high, replay to catch up when you change `recovery.conf` might take a *long* time and require *lots* of WAL storage, so this is only really good if the unstable site is big but doesn't change a vast amount relative to its total size.